# Evaluate a custom expression with angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to evaluate a logical expression through angularjs directive.

Ex:

`<div myDir expr="(element2 || (element1 && x==true))">
    element
</div>`

The reason I'm using directive is because I want to show/hide elements based on the accessible lists which I get with a service. I know we can use $eval for expresssions like (x==true && y==false). But what I'm trying to do I've to check if element1(which is not en expression) exists in a list and combine them to evaluate an expression. So if element1 exists in my list and not element2, the expression will be (false || (true && x==true)). Is there way we can do this?

Comment: Why not ngShow or ngIf? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: So you want to check if an element exists in a list? `myArray.indexOf(element) != -1` ... and then combine that w/some other boolean condition? What am I missing? :)

Comment: @SunilD. Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. But how can I recognize them as element so that I can check it in list and combine the results with other expression?

Comment: To "recognize them as element" they need to be values attached to the scope of the directive. I think this is why we are asking the questions above. `ngIf`, `ngShow`, etc. use `$eval`, and you should probably use one of those three. In this case, you need to make sure your directive's scope has access to everything it needs: element1, element2, and a list. Try editing your question and adding the code you've tried if this doesn't help :)